# how to bind the gridview?

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding

I've got a problem binding one of my table to GridView. I tried everything but nothing helped.
I have a Search button and I want it to show me the result of my search and I've got a DropDownList which binds to another table.

Here's the code:

```
SqlConnection my_cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NIMA-PC;Initial Catalog=PDFha;Integrated Security=True");
my_cn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Books.Name,Books.Subject,Books.PublisherName,Books.Summery FROM Books WHERE (Books.Subject= '" + subList.SelectedValue.ToString() + "') AND (Books.Name= '" + searchName.Text + "')", my_cn);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
adapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read()==true)
{
   GridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
my_cn.Close();
```

Nothing happens when I click the button
I know that there is something wrong with my C# code but I am unable to Identify it.
Appreciate any comment.

Comment: GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: @Shree tried it,wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:- You are missing `DataBind` method, apart from this I don't know why you are calling `DataReader` again, have removed that code too. Also, Please use paramaterized query to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Something like:- `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()`

```
SqlConnection my_cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NIMA-PC;Initial Catalog=PDFha;Integrated Security=True");
my_cn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Books.Name,Books.Subject,Books.PublisherName,Books.Summery FROM Books WHERE (Books.Subject= '" + subList.SelectedValue.ToString() + "') AND (Books.Name= '" + searchName.Text + "')", my_cn);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
adapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
my_cn.Close();
```

Comment: again tried it,but it doesn't even show my gridview... it's like it doesn't even there?

Comment: @NimaSharify - Have you debugged the code and saw if `dt` is populating?

Comment: yes the sql code is fine and the query returns 3 rows.
if that is what your asking?'

Comment: @NimaSharify - Nope! I am asking have debugged your C# code? Please check if your datatable is populating or not. Alos, you can directly bind the datasource if you don't have multiple tables, like this:- `GridView1.DataSource = ds`

Comment: thank you for your answer I directly connected the dataset and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the corrected code

```
SqlConnection my_cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NIMA-PC;Initial Catalog=PDFha;Integrated Security=True");
my_cn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Books.Name,Books.Subject,Books.PublisherName,Books.Summery FROM Books WHERE (Books.Subject= '" + subList.SelectedValue.ToString() + "') AND (Books.Name= '" + searchName.Text + "')", my_cn);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
adapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
//Modified start
//You don't need SQLReader, While loop
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
//Modified End
my_cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (dr.Read()==true)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: tried it,but it doesn't even show my gridview...
it's like it doesn't even there?

Comment: Is your sql query returning any data ? Does your DataTable dt have rows in it ?

Answer (score 0):

you missed  this

GridView1.DataBind();